# Count match in 2 pandas dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes containing text as list in each row. This one is called df

```
Datum   File    File_type   Text    
Datum                                               
2000-01-27  2000-01-27  0864820040_000127_04.txt    _04     [business, date, jan, heineken, starts, integr..
```

and i have another one, df_lm which looks like this

```
List_type   Words
0   LM_cnstrain.    [abide, abiding, bound, bounded, commit, commi...
1   LM_litigius.    [abovementioned, abrogate, abrogated, abrogate...
2   LM_modal_me.    [can, frequently, generally, likely, often, ou...
3   LM_modal_st.    [always, best, clearly, definitely, definitive...
4   LM_modal_wk.    [almost, apparently, appeared, appearing, appe...
```

I want to create new columns in df, where the match of words should be counted, so for example how many words are there from df_lm.Words[0] in df.Text[0]

Note: df has ca 500 rows and df_lm has 6 -> so i need to create 6 new columns in df so that the updated df looks somewhat like this

```
    Datum   ...LM_cnstrain  LM_litigius  Lm_modal_me  ...
2000-01-27  ...   5            3             4
2000-02-25 ...    7            1             0
```

I hope i was clear on my question.
Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
i have already done smth. similar by creating a list and loop over it, but as the lists in df_lm are very long this is not an option.

The code looked like this:

```
result_list[]
for file in file_list:
    count_growth = 0
    for word in text.split ():
        if word in growth:
            count_growth = count_growth +1
    a={'Grwoth':count_growth}
    result_list.append(a)
```

Comment: Are you only looking for a solution where you can match two df columns and get a count of elements matched? Rest df transpose can you take care?

Comment: what do you mean by 'Rest df transpose can you take care'?

Comment: Addition of columns in the original dataframe...

Comment: Guess i know how to add the new columns to orginal dataframe.
I would have tried smth linke: df['name_new_column'] = ...

Answer (score 0):

According to my comments you can try something like this:

The below code has to run in a loop where text column from 1st df has to be matched with all 6 from next and make column with value from `len(c)`

```
desc = df_lm.iloc[0,1]
matches = df.text.isin(desc)
result = df.text[matches]
```

If this helps you, let me know otherwise will update/delete the answer

Comment: doesnt help, because for your a, i have on average a list of 250 words / cell (for 550 rows) and for b i have ca. 5000 entries/cell

Comment: Doesn't matter, how long the lists are. Instead of "a" and "b" you have to pass your columns!!

Comment: i have missunderstodd you at first but if i try i get
error: unhashable type: 'list'
maybe i havent been clear enough: my df looks like:
0  ... [apple, pie,coke...]
1  ...[jaw, bone, cricket,...]
so if i understand pandas right my column df.Text would be a series of lists

Comment: The same example above or when u pass df column to set ?

Comment: your example works fine,
when i pass in the columns i get the error: i did:
a = df.Text
b = df_lm.iloc[0,1] 
c= (set(a)& set(b))
len(c)

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184039/discussion-between-user10395806-and-rahul-agarwal).

Answer (score 0):

So ive come to the following solution:

```
    for file in file_list:
        count_lm_constraint = 0
        count_lm_litigious = 0
        count_lm_modal_me = 0
          for word in text.split()
        if word in df_lm.iloc[0,1]:
                count_lm_constraint = count_lm_constraint +1 
            if word in df_lm.iloc[1,1]:
                count_lm_litigious = count_lm_litigious +1
            if word in df_lm.iloc[2,1]:
                count_lm_modal_me = count_lm_modal_me +1
            a={"File": name, "Text": text,'lm_uncertain':count_lm_uncertain,'lm_positive':count_lm_positive ....}
result_list.append(a)
```